# jquery kwicks and css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a bit of trouble with kwicks:

http://ftp.crashboxcreative.com/ftp/EastsideBaptist/EBC-Final/
(I've changed the jQuery to show the drop-down with issue.)
kwick_3 is the one with issue.  There's a gap b/t kwick 2 and 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your CSS, your submenu definition is set to a width of 620px... it should be 600px since each of your Kwicks is 200px wide.

```
.subMenu{
    background: #b1d0a4;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 9;
    text-indent: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'd like the menu to be 620px.  When I change it to your CSS (I've tried that too), the menu shrinks below the width of the main menu.  When I try to tinker with the numbers, the menu doesn't change.

Comment: Well the 20 pixel gap (that you had, I don't see it now) was because the kwick_3 menu is only 200px wide and aligned to the right. Maybe try making all the menus 207px wide or just set kwick_3 to 220px wide. That should get rid of the gap.

Comment: For some reason when I make them 207px wide, the gap still appears.

Comment: I don't see the gap anymore... is this still an issue? (I looked at your site with FF, Chrome and IE)